# SharePoint Site Directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to save all site collections and Sites to a list in order to keep track of how many sites and subsites sharepoint are using. Site Directory seemed like a good thing but if I understand it rightly only site collections are added to it. 
My Idea is therefore to via the object model add all sites to the Site Directory. But then I could add them to any custom list and get the same function as Site Directory has. So what is Site Directory used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/CH011714461033.aspx